# Simple Test Class for simple controller

Tags: unit-test

I have a very simple class that i don't know how to write a test for, what i don't know is how to pass the CaseID from a test class to the controller. I'm working on a sorted list for a VF email template ( https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_with_apex.htm )

My Controller is:

```
public class CaseCommentSort {
    public Id CaseId {get; set;}

   public List<CaseComment> getCaseComments() {
       return [
           SELECT CreatedDate, CommentBody FROM CaseComment
           WHERE ParentId = :this.CaseId ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC
       ];
   }
}
```

And the test class i'm trying to write is something like this:

```
@isTest 
public class testCaseCommentSort {

    static testMethod void testCaseCommentSort(){
        Case c = new Case( Origin = 'Phone', Data_Accurate__c = false, ReadyToCreateCall__c = false, Job_Type__c = 'Service',
                     CustomerOrderNo__c ='232', DetailsConfirmed__c=false);
        insert c;            
        CaseCommentSort.CaseId ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally for a controller, I would expect a constructor that would take an Id (or something like that). You don't have a constructor, but then again, neither does the example that you were working from.

What you do have, however, is a public property (basically, a class variable that has a setter and a getter). `CaseId`.

Since your property isn't static, you'll need to create an instance of your controller class to get/set the value of `CaseId`. That simply looks like this:

```
CaseCommentSort ccs = new CaseCommentSort();
```

From there, you can call methods defined as public (such as `getCaseComments()`), and get/set public class variables and public properties.

Your test class so far would look like this:

```
@isTest 
public class testCaseCommentSort {

    static testMethod void testCaseCommentSort(){
        Case c = new Case( Origin = 'Phone', Data_Accurate__c = false, ReadyToCreateCall__c = false, Job_Type__c = 'Service',
                     CustomerOrderNo__c ='232', DetailsConfirmed__c=false);
        insert c;

        CaseCommentSort ccs = new CaseCommentSort();
        // Since you have inserted your test `Case` record, it will have an Id.
        // I believe that the Id field is the only field that is automatically set
        //   after you insert an SObject record.
        // If you had an insert trigger on Case, which set Subject or Owner (for example),
        //   you would need to query your newly inserted case to get that data.
        ccs.CaseId = c.Id;
    }
}
```

Test methods have 3 phases:

1. Set up your test data
2. Call the method that you want to test
3. Make assertions to verify that the thing you're testing behaved the way you expected it to

Code coverage is merely a side effect of proper testing (coverage is also the only metric Salesforce can enforce).

You've taken care of part of phase 1, but if we take a look at the controller that you're testing, the actual thing that you care about are `CaseComment` records (and you haven't inserted any of those yet).

You'll need to do this after inserting your case (since a case comment can't exist without a case). Setting up a case comment or two is pretty easy.

```
CaseComment testComment =  new CaseComment(
    ParentId = c.Id,
    CommentBody = 'test comment'
);
insert testComment;
```

After that, you can move to phase 2 of your test, calling your target method (and generally speaking *only* one method. A single method is a unit, and we're doing *unit* testing, not wholebunchamethods testing).

```
// Using Test.startTest/Test.stopTest isn't absolutely required here, but
//   it's a good habit to get into.
// Using these become important when you test larger pieces of code that interact
//   with more things.
Test.startTest();
List<CaseComment> results = ccs.getCaseComments();
Test.stopTest();
```

Finally, the most important part of your test, verifying results. Verifying the results is what makes a test 'a test'. Without verifying results, you won't know if your method was built correctly. If you don't verify results, you could be getting comments for an entirely different case, or no comments at all.

Since you want the comments to be returned in a specific order, it would be good to verify that. `CreatedDate` only has granularity down to the second, and that field isn't user-editable, so creating case comments in the test directly may or may not work. Instead, I'd suggest looking at [using Test.loadData()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_load_data.htm) to load data from a csv file uploaded as a static resource. Using that method, you will be able to specify the `CreatedDate`.

Provided you do that, this final phase of testing is also simple.

```
// Verification step 1, get the data that you expect your method to return.
// In this case, we basically take the query from your controller
List<CaseComment> expectedResults = [SELECT CreatedDate, CommentBody FROM CaseComment WHERE ParentId = :c.Id];

// Verification step 2, use system.assertEquals
// list.equals() checks to see that two lists are the same size, contain the same
//   data, and that data is in the same order.
System.assertEquals(true, results.equals(expectedResults), 'Some descriptive explanation of what went wrong');
```

You might ask why I'm suggesting you basically copy/paste some code from the thing you're trying to test into your test. It does seem a bit silly, but there is a reason for it.

Your test(s), specifically the assertions you make, tell people what the expected result should be. It doesn't really care about the implementation (how the thing you're testing actually arrives at its answer), just that the end state is the same. In this case, your code was simple enough that the description of the desired end state just happened to be basically identical to the implementation.

Again, in larger, more complex classes, the code that you use to gather the expected output of the test run of your class/method won't look nearly as similar.

Once you have that test in place, I would suggest writing at least one more test. One that verifies what happens when a `Case` doesn't have any comments. Testing more than one 'path' (or one set of circumstances that a piece of code can find itself trying to handle) gives you assurance of your code's robustness (its ability to handle many situations, even less than ideal situations). It also gives you a level of assurance of the behavior that other pieces of code (that use the code you're testing) should expect.

In this case, writing a test to verify that if a `Case` doesn't have any comments, it returns an empty `List<CaseComment>` lets you know that any other code that uses your controller can expect that the result of calling `getCaseComments()` will never be null. That information can save work down the line (given `List<CaseComment> result = ccs.getCaseComments();`, no need to check `if(result == null)...`). You could directly use the result in a for loop without worry.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a variable with the type of your class and then set the CaseId variable and call the method from there. See code example below:

```
CaseCommentSort controller = new CaseCommentSort();
controller.CaseId = c.Id;
controller.getCaseComments();
```

Comment: Dan, this is a pretty weak answer, Can you give the OP more specific details?

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following changes in your test class.

```
CaseCommentSort cs = new CaseCommentSort();    
CaseCommentSort.CaseId = c.id;
CaseCommentSort.getCaseComments();
```

Comment: This is also a weak answer, and is almost exactly the same as an answer that came before it. This answer would be better if you went into detail about (at the very least) 1) What you think the problem (that the person asking the question) is running into, 2) How your solution addresses that issue. As is, this answer isn't very helpful to making the OP (original poster) understand what the issue is, or how to avoid similar situations in the future. It's also not very helpful for other people who may visit this question in the future. For those reasons, I have downvoted this answer.